# setState start to work recursively in React.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, reactjs

I start to work with react.js and create a component Box, `state = {pageNumber: 1, dataForTable:''}`. I insert two components in it - Pagination and Table. When click to Pagination it give number of page to Box. Box state change then it render and then Pagination render too. Then I set ajax to server, get new data for table and then Box render for second time to render `Tables`.

In which function should I put ajax logic? When i put it in `componentDidUpdate` setState start to work recursively.

In future will be more components in `<Box/ >` which will change `<Tables />`.

Comment: Please add more details to your question and the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is your setup:

```
var React = require('react');

var ComponentBox = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Table />
                <Pagination />
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = ComponentBox;
```

1. Your table component should never handle data, you should "feed" data to your component. So you should have a prop receiving data in your table component.
2. Pagination component should pass an event to ComponentBox telling ComponentBox to get the data - so ajax should happen in your ComponentBox (read more on flux if you wish)

Here's the suggested solution for you

```
var React = require('react');

var ComponentBox = React.createClass({

    handlePageChange: function(startIndex, size) {
        // do your ajax here
        // set your data to state which causes re-render
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Table data={this.state.tableData} />
                <Pagination onPageChange={this.handlePageChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = ComponentBox;
```

inside your pagination component, remember to pass the information out through props onPageChange =)

Hope this is clear enough for you.